# Copy state (array) and keep it static

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array (myArray) that i manipulate with buttons, after each button-click I want to store the previous state in an array as a history and I got an "undo-button" that just pops the last entry from my history-array and via setMyArray(history.pop()) I want to set the myArray back to the value before I pressed the button, but somehow the elements in my history-array always update when I press a button. How can i "dislink" them?

Comment: React makes a shallow copy of the state, you'll need to clone all individual items manually before adding them to the new state (though maybe cloning just the one that changes will be enough in your case)

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova why not add an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova okay I guessed something like this, but it also happens when I want to add the array in my historyArray via [...myArray] - so I really have to loop over all the items and store them manually?

Comment: @Codebling because I'm lazy :)

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova haha that's fair. Can't give you magic internet points for a comment, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the array with items as a room with people in it. When React creates a new state it makes a new room and fills it with same people. If you add or remove people from the group you can go through history nicely, each room will be filled with the right number of correct individuals. But if someone dies, or, say, changes gender, that it will no longer work, you go to the previous room, but people are not quite the same. So when a change to an item happens you need to make a copy of it and replace the object in the new state (`[...myArray]` will not do it for you, it's the same shallow copy)